# Where should questions about index.ros.org be posted?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Github [repository](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/index.ros.org) has disabled the *Issues* tab.

Should ROS Discourse be used instead?

Or here, on ROS Answers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347818/where-should-questions-about-index.ros.org-be-posted?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As always questions should be asked here on answers.ros.org

The repository you have linked to contains 100% auto-generated content. If you want to make a bug report (about the structure or generation and not content) or feature request of the site it can be filed on [rosindex](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosindex/issues)

Any content specific issues should be filed with the package from which the data is aggregated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-30**:
I only now found [this page](https://index.ros.org/contribute/#contribute-to-the-ros-index-website), which includes a link to `github/ros-infrastructure/rosindex`. It's a bit hidden, and there is a much more prominent link at the bottom left of each page with a Github icon and a `ros-infrastructure` label. That's how I arrived at `github/ros-infrastructure/index.ros.org`.